# Detect Adapter Connection Type (Specifically Cellular)

Tags: c#, windows-7

I need to differentiate network connection types (on standard windows 7 PCs) to initiate some business workflow. I can detect Ethernet and WiFi adapters without much trouble but I'm struggling to identify cellular adapter aircards. I've tried Win32_NetworkAdapter* and NetworkInterfaceType and the Verizon, Sprint, and AT&T cards are all reported as Ethernet devices.

The application cannot run on any version of .NET greater than V3.5 SP1. Does anyone have any idea how one goes about definitively differentiating a cellular connection via an aircard from a standard Ethernet connection?

Comment: no - that is not possible in a robust manner!

Comment: As you've seen some vendors lie.  And if you have NetMotion installed... Anyway, we manage determining what is actually on the box with (W)indows (M)anagement (I)nstrumentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx which allows us to differentiate between adapters to a greater degree than NetworkInformation seems to.  For example we are able distinguish between physical and other adapter types.